# what precautions should i do to protect my dog from little worms and ticks?

Tags: dogs, health, parasites

I have a long-haired dog who always picks up little worms in his fur (difficult to pull them off), what should I do to overcome my problem?

Comment: what type of worms do your dog get.please add more information to your question.

Comment: Hi Baneen! Can you tell us where you are from to help better guide you? :) Also if you could post photos of the worms that would greatly improve your question